# vba excel get monitor of workbook

Tags: excel, vba, display, monitor

Currently I have two monitors (side by side) and in Excel the workbooks are opened on a specific monitor. I wish to move the visible workbooks to the opposite monitor. So if the workbook is on monitor 1, I wish to move it to monitor 2 and vice versa. I have code which can do everything I need except getting the correct monitor a workbook is on. So for example if I have four workbooks open, they could be on two different monitors. Then I would like to switch them.
I do hope this is possible! I can move a workbook from the right monitor to the left monitor but it does not determine the correct monitor and that is my issue. See the below code in VBA for Excel.
Does anyone have a solution which works?

There might be some redundant code in between because I have been trying a lot of things in different ways.

```
Option Explicit

Private Const ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS As Long = -1
Private Const DISPLAY_DEVICE_ATTACHED_TO_DESKTOP As Long = &H1
Private Const CCHDEVICENAME As Long = 32
Private Const CCHFORMNAME As Long = 32

Private Type DISPLAY_DEVICE
  cb As Long
  DeviceName As String * CCHDEVICENAME
  DeviceString As String * 128
  StateFlags As Long
  DeviceID As String * 128
  DeviceKey As String * 128
End Type

Private Type DEVMODE
  dmDeviceName As String * CCHDEVICENAME
  dmSpecVersion As Integer
  dmDriverVersion As Integer
  dmSize As Integer
  dmDriverExtra As Integer
  dmFields As Long
  dmOrientation As Integer
  dmPaperSize As Integer
  dmPaperLength As Integer
  dmPaperWidth As Integer
  dmScale As Integer
  dmCopies As Integer
  dmDefaultSource As Integer
  dmPrintQuality As Integer
  dmColor As Integer
  dmDuplex As Integer
  dmYResolution As Integer
  dmTTOption As Integer
  dmCollate As Integer
  dmFormName As String * CCHFORMNAME
  dmLogPixels As Integer
  dmBitsPerPel As Long
  dmPelsWidth As Long
  dmPelsHeight As Long
  dmDisplayFlags As Long
  dmDisplayFrequency As Long
End Type

Private Declare PtrSafe Function EnumDisplayDevices Lib "user32.dll" Alias "EnumDisplayDevicesA" (ByVal lpDevice As String, ByVal iDevNum As Long, ByRef lpDisplayDevice As DISPLAY_DEVICE, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function EnumDisplaySettings Lib "user32.dll" Alias "EnumDisplaySettingsA" (ByVal lpszDeviceName As String, ByVal iModeNum As Long, ByRef lpDevMode As DEVMODE) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32.dll" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWndParent As LongPtr, ByVal hWndChildAfter As LongPtr, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As LongPtr, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long, ByVal cx As Long, ByVal cy As Long, ByVal uFlags As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function MoveWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long, ByVal nWidth As Long, ByVal nHeight As Long, ByVal bRepaint As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function ShowWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long

Private Const HWND_TOPMOST = -1
Private Const HWND_NOTOPMOST = -2
Private Const SWP_NOMOVE = &H2
Private Const SWP_NOSIZE = &H1
Private Const SWP_SHOWWINDOW = &H40
Private Const SWP_HIDEWINDOW = &H80
Private Const SW_MAXIMIZE = 3

Public FirstMonitor As String
Public SecondMonitor As String
Public oppositeDisplayName As String
Public DeviceName As String

Sub MoveExcelWorkbook()
    Dim hWnd As LongPtr
    Dim excelApp As Object
    Dim wb As Workbook
   
    ' Create Excel application object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set excelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If Err.number <> 0 Then
        Set excelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
   
    If excelApp Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Failed to create or get Excel Application object."
        Exit Sub
    End If
   
    DisplayNumberOfMonitors
   
    ' Move each workbook to the target monitor
    For Each wb In excelApp.Workbooks
    If wb.windows(1).Visible = True Then
    Debug.Print "wb.Name: " & wb.name
    wb.activate
      hWnd = FindWindowEx(0&, 0&, "XLMAIN", vbNullString)
    If hWnd <> 0 Then
        ' Move the Excel Workbook to:
        If MoveWindowToOppositeDisplay(hWnd) Then
            ' Maximize the Excel Workbook on opposite display
            If MaximizeWindow(hWnd) Then
                Debug.Print "Excel Workbook moved and maximized on " & oppositeDisplayName
            Else
                Debug.Print "Failed to maximize Excel Workbook on " & oppositeDisplayName
            End If
        Else
            Debug.Print "Failed to move Excel Workbook to " & oppositeDisplayName
        End If
    Else
        Debug.Print "Excel Workbook not found."
    End If
    End If
    Next wb
   
End Sub

Private Function MoveWindowToOppositeDisplay(ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As Boolean
   
    ' Retrieve the current display device name for the window
    DeviceName = Space(128)
    Call GetWindowDeviceName(hWnd, DeviceName)
   
   
    ' Determine the name of the opposite display
    If StrComp(DeviceName, FirstMonitor, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        oppositeDisplayName = SecondMonitor
    ElseIf StrComp(DeviceName, SecondMonitor, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        oppositeDisplayName = FirstMonitor
    Else
        ' Window is not on display1 or display7, do not move
        MoveWindowToOppositeDisplay = False
        Exit Function
    End If
   
    ' Move the window to the opposite display
    MoveWindowToOppositeDisplay = MoveWindowToDisplay(hWnd, oppositeDisplayName)
End Function


Function MoveWindowToDisplay(ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal displayDeviceName As String) As Boolean
    Dim NullCharPos As Long
   
    ' Check if the window is already on the desired display
    If StrComp(DeviceName, displayDeviceName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            MoveWindowToDisplay = MoveWindow(hWnd, 1920, 0, 1920, 1080, True) ' Adjust width and height as needed
        MoveWindowToDisplay = True

    Else
        ' Move the window to the desired display
        MoveWindowToDisplay = MoveWindow(hWnd, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, True) ' Adjust width and height as needed
        MoveWindowToDisplay = True
    End If
End Function

Private Function IsWindowOnDisplay(ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal displayDeviceName As String) As Boolean
    Dim DeviceName As String
    Dim NullCharPos As Long
   
    DeviceName = Space(128)
    Call GetWindowDeviceName(hWnd, DeviceName)
   
    NullCharPos = InStr(DeviceName, vbNullChar)
    If NullCharPos > 0 Then
        DeviceName = Left$(DeviceName, NullCharPos - 1)
    End If
   
    IsWindowOnDisplay = (StrComp(DeviceName, displayDeviceName, vbTextCompare) = 0)
End Function

Private Sub GetWindowDeviceName(ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByRef DeviceName As String)
    Dim dd As DISPLAY_DEVICE
    dd.cb = Len(dd)
    Call EnumDisplayDevices(vbNullString, 0, dd, 0)
    Call EnumDisplayDevices(dd.DeviceName, 0, dd, 0)
    DeviceName = dd.DeviceName
End Sub

Private Function MaximizeWindow(ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As Boolean
    ' Maximize the window
    MaximizeWindow = ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_MAXIMIZE)
End Function

Sub DisplayNumberOfMonitors()
    Dim MonitorsAndScreenSize As Variant
    Dim MONITORINFO As New Collection
    Dim indAdapter As Long
    Dim ddAdapters As DISPLAY_DEVICE
    ddAdapters.cb = Len(ddAdapters)
   
    indAdapter = 0
    Do Until EnumDisplayDevices(vbNullString, indAdapter, ddAdapters, 0) = 0
        If (ddAdapters.StateFlags And DISPLAY_DEVICE_ATTACHED_TO_DESKTOP) = DISPLAY_DEVICE_ATTACHED_TO_DESKTOP Then
            Dim NullCharPos As Long
            NullCharPos = InStr(ddAdapters.DeviceName, vbNullChar)
            Dim CurDeviceName As String
            If NullCharPos > 0 Then
                CurDeviceName = Left$(ddAdapters.DeviceName, NullCharPos - 1)
            Else
                CurDeviceName = ddAdapters.DeviceName
            End If
            Dim dmode As DEVMODE
            dmode.dmSize = Len(dmode)
            EnumDisplaySettings CurDeviceName, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, dmode
            MonitorsAndScreenSize = CurDeviceName
            MONITORINFO.Add MonitorsAndScreenSize
        End If
        indAdapter = indAdapter + 1
    Loop
   
    ' Display monitor information
    Dim monitorInfoString As String
    For Each MonitorsAndScreenSize In MONITORINFO
        monitorInfoString = monitorInfoString & vbCrLf & MonitorsAndScreenSize
    Next MonitorsAndScreenSize
    Debug.Print monitorInfoString
    'MsgBox monitorInfoString
    Debug.Print MONITORINFO.count
    FirstMonitor = MONITORINFO.item(1)
    SecondMonitor = MONITORINFO.item(2)
End Sub
```